# Dynamically creating labels in an if...then statement

Tags: vb.net

This may be simple, but im having a tough go at it.  I'm trying to make a "review" section in a step through form, where the user can see everything that has been entered and if they choose go back and "edit" that information again.  One section only has to show the information that has been added by the user, basically if they don't select a certain checkbox there is no reason to display the info for that box.

I want to to dynamically create labels in a Panel (Panel7) on a TabPage (TabPage3), only for the checkbox information that was selected.  This is what I have right now, and I am unable to see anything on the page, I have also tried without the panel and straight onto the tabpage itself to no avail.

```
    MsgBox(CurPat, MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
    If (CurPat = "True") Then
        Dim lblTemp As New Label
        lblTemp.Text = "Inquirer has used service previously: " & CurPat
        lblTemp.Location = New Point(x, y)
        Me.Panel7.Controls.Add(lblTemp)
    End If
```

the message box beforehand is just to tell me that it is assigned a value of "True" which i assure it is.
Thank you in advance for any help.
-NickG

Comment: Did you try setting its Visible to True?

Comment: x and y are inside the visible area of the panel?? did you move it to front?? set visible to true?

Comment: Did you also set the size and location of the panel? Is its visible property true?

Comment: BESIDES all the suggestions above... did you actually guarantee the code inside the if is executing?

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem with:

```
If (CurPat = "True")
```

Which should be:

```
If (CurPat = True)
```

Just to make sure, put a message box inside the `If` block to see if it's being triggered, and another one in an `Else` block.

```
If (CurPat = True)
    MessageBox.Show("CurPat = True")
    ...
Else
    MessageBox.Show("CurPat = False")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you want to calculate the proper X, Y locations of each label, set each newly created label to have Autosize = False and Dock = Top. This way, they will stack one on top of the other in the Panel. But note, they will be stacked with the first label on the bottom and the newest on the top. You'll have to work that part out.